# Web service error from SSIS package: "There was no endpoint listening at https://www.SomeWebservicesURL.com" after deploying to sql server

Tags: c#, ssis, endpoint

Can someone please help me here?  I Googled and tried many suggestions with no success.  Many thanks in advance!  Below is description of my issue:

I created a SSIS package using the Script Task to consume a web services in WSDL SOAP.  It runs fine on my local machine but it is giving me the > [ There was no endpoint listening at https://SomeWebServices/servicetest.asmx that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 00.00.000.00:443
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream()]

Below is my code:

```
     BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();            
  binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
  binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
  binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
  binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
  binding.AllowCookies = false;
  binding.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
  binding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
  binding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text;
  binding.TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
  binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
  binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
  binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;

  binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
  binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;
  binding.Security.Transport.Realm = string.Empty;
 
  EndpointAddress epaddress = new EndpointAddress("https://SomeWebServices/servicetest.asmx");             
  return new ServiceSoapClient(binding, epaddress);
```

Comment: That sounds like a firewall issue or it could be a name resolution issue too.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I forgot to mention that I was able to open the link https://SomeWebServices/servicetest.asmx in the IE browser so that makes me think the firewall is not the issue.

Comment: You can but can agent?

Comment: Server, check the server where you deployed the ssis package.  Can you access the URL from the server?  Start there.

Comment: What Tim and Keith said.  Just because firewall rules allow you to get to the web service from your machine doesn't mean that other rules prevent it from the server.

Comment: Thanks All for responding.  I was told by my networking team that since the IE browser on the server can access the https://SomeWebServices/servicetest.asmx webservice from the server, it proves that the network traffic is not being blocked to https://SomeWebServices/servicetest.asmx.

@Duston, can you please explain what other possible rules could prevent it from the server so that I can talk with my network team again?

Many thanks in advance!!!

Comment: The first thing I'd check is the ID the package is running under.  When you connect to it using IE, you're using your credentials (whatever you used to log into the server) whereas the application consuming the service is running under (possibly) a different set of credentials.  The application's credentials may not be able to access the service, or the credentials are prohibited from being used as a service account.